# Demo program error: '' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, qt, netbeans, scope, qlabel

I am new to Qt and have started with the demo program found [here](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.6/tutorials-addressbook-part7.html).  I have renamed the class AddressBook to Dialog.  It compiles and executes just fine.  I want to add my own code to the example, so I add a new label as a private member of the class:

```
private:
QCheckBox *native;
QLabel *integerLabel;
QLabel *doubleLabel;
QLabel *itemLabel;
...
QLabel *questionLabel;
QLabel *warningLabel;
QLabel *errorLabel;
QLabel *newLabel;     // <== This is new
QErrorMessage *errorMessageDialog;
```

In the constructor Dialog::Dialog I (try to) allocate memory to the variables:

```
warningLabel = new QLabel;
warningLabel->setFrameStyle(frameStyle);
QPushButton *warningButton = new QPushButton(tr("QMessageBox::&warning()"));

errorLabel = new QLabel;
errorLabel->setFrameStyle(frameStyle);
QPushButton *errorButton =
new QPushButton(tr("QErrorMessage::showM&essage()"));

newLabel = new QLabel;    // <== Error
newLabel->setFrameStyle(frameStyle);
```

As far as I can tell, I have created and allocated the variable correctly in this class, by copy and pasting *errorLabel and changing its name.  Yet the compiler issues the error:

> error: 'newLabel' was not declared in this scope

When I click the error, it takes me to the "new" line in the constructor.  If I remark out the two lines in the constructor referring to newLabel, the program compiles.  It IS in this scope in my mind.  What mistake am I making here?  How do we prevent these type issues in the future?  (I have searched tens of similar posts and was able to identify the OP's mistake in 30s or less, but I cannot find my own, nor can I find a post where variables are declared in the class, but not found in the constructor.)

Thanks in advance,
Kyle

Comment: So I have to ask. Did you actually save your header file after you added the `QLabel *newLabel` line to it?

Comment: Good question, and the answer is yes (many times now).  Thanks.

Comment: Are you using Qt creator? If so, what happens when you right click 'newLabel' in your constructor and select 'follow symbol under cursor' from the context menu? Have you tried rebuilding your project?

Comment: I'm using NetBeans 7.3.  Doing the similar task to what you're asking, NetBeans IDE says "unable to resolve identifier newLabel".  I have done clean builds.  Perhaps I need to re-make the entire project.  If that does not work, I may have to post the project in its entirety.

Comment: I got the similar error while I was editing my file using sublime text editor. I closed all the shitty sublime text windows. Reopened files with vi editor and then re did the changes and everything worked. Seriously this kind of shit I hate. anyway you answer helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem.  Even though it is not the answer I expected, I post this answer just in case it is helpful to the rest of the community.

I created a new project and copied the cpp/h files from the non-working project into the new project.  The new project compiles.  With the new project I can now add other private variables to the class and access them in the constructor (as well as the IDE).  All parameters I have easy access to show the projects to be identical, yet one compiles and the other does not.  I can only conclude the project itself somehow became corrupted (which does not inspire confidence).

While I am relieved it was not a stupid programmatic mistake on my part, I am disappointed in not being able to find and fix whatever was wrong with the project files.  Thanks to all those who offered suggestions.